# C Segmentation Fault while converting numbers to strings

Tags: c, memory, segmentation-fault

I have been coding for a couple years now and wanted to learn C. I need a function that does not use printf but instead ends up with a string as output since I am trying to target a platform with custom I/O. The function needs to calculate prime factors of a given int n.

I have tested the function that evaluates the prime factors before and it worked, however, the string conversion function has not worked yet.
The segmentation fault error:

```
    ~/Development/C/First  ./run.sh                                                                                                                                           ✔ 
./run.sh: line 2: 21387 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ./a.out
Compilation failed!
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int* primeFactors(int n);
char* primeFactorsAsString(int n);

int main()
{
    int number = 117;
    printf(primeFactorsAsString(number));
    return 0;
}

int* primeFactors(int n)
{
    if (n < 2) {
        static int result[2];
        result[0] = 1;
        result[1] = n;
        return result;
    }

    int size = 0;
    static int factors[33];
    //Max int has 32 factors, plus first spot in array for length of array.

    while (n%2 == 0)
    {
        size++;
        factors[size] = 2;
        n = n/2;
    }
 
    for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(n); i = i+2)
    {
        while (n%i == 0)
        {
            size++;
            factors[size] = i;
            n = n/i;
        }
    }
    if (n > 2)
    {
        size++;
        factors[size] = n;
    }

    factors[0] = size;
    return factors;
}

char* primeFactorsAsString(int n) {
    int *factors;

    if (factors[0] > 25) {
        return "TO BIG";
    }

    factors = primeFactors(n);
    static char result[100];
    char buffer[100];
    for (int i = 1; i < result[0]; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d * ", result[i]);
        strcat(result, buffer);

    }
    sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", result[result[0]]);
    strcat(result, buffer);

    return result;
}
```

It is most likely that the issue occurred in the primeFactorsAsString Function. I don't know where though. If its important, here is also the run.sh script that i made:

```
gcc main.c -lm
[ $? -eq 0 ] && ./a.out || echo "Compilation failed!"
```

Comment: The most likely problem is that you are overflowing `result` by adding more than 100 characters into it.  The fix would be to either make `result` larger, or check its current length before appending more characters to it so as not to overflow it, or calling `strncat()` instead of `strcat()`, or (if you are using C++ and not C) using `std::string` to collect chars instead of a char-array, or some combination of the above.

Comment: I don't think you initialise `factors` to anything so dereferencing it is a bad idea. (I mean you initialise it after checking `factors[0]`)

Comment: `strcat(result, buffer);` risks overflowing `result`.

Comment: @Lala5th `static int factors[33];` is `static`.  It is initialized to zeroes at load time.

Comment: Lasslos05, Post a [mcve].

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I mean `int *factors` in `primeFactorsAsString`.

Comment: @Lala5th Fair enough. `int *factors; if (factors[0] > 25)` is a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I didn't initialize factors before the if statement, switched both of them and now I get just zero as output. That's not what i want but not the error either therefore a solution.

Edit: I found out the second issue as well. I referenced the wrong array in the for loop. Here is the working function:

```
char* primeFactorsAsString(int n) {
    int *factors;

    factors = primeFactors(n);

    if (factors[0] > 25) {
        return "TO BIG";
    }
    static char result[100];
    char buffer[100];
    for (int i = 1; i < factors[0]; i++)
    {
        sprintf(buffer, "%d * ", factors[i]);
        strcat(result, buffer);
        

    }
    sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", factors[factors[0]]);
    strcat(result, buffer);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Tip: when able _declare_ and _initialize_ in one step. `int *factors; factors = primeFactors(n);` --> `int *factors = primeFactors(n);`.

Comment: `primeFactorsAsString()` risks overflow of `static char result[100];` should `primeFactorsAsString()` get called more than once.  Better reset `result` to zero length at the start of the function or provide other means to form the string.

Comment: Perhaps [Too big](https://greedhead.net/which-is-correct-to-big-or-too-big/#Which_is_correct_to_big_or_too_big) instead of "TO BIG".

Answer (score 0):

`printf(primeFactorsAsString(number));` -- needs format specifier %s, the function returns string.

`sprintf(buffer, "%d\n", result[result[0]]);` -- result[0] returns a char (as defined by `static char result[100];` so you can't index an array with a char.

`int *factors;` -- is not initialized, always initialize your pointers to NULL.

`if (factors[0] > 25)` -- `factor[0]` is out of scope. maybe you would want to declare it as a global variable to be able to access it within the primeFactorsAsString function.

Comment: "always initialize your pointers to NULL." --> Disagree.  Better as `int *factors = primeFactors(n);`.